# SLD Principle with clauses that are not horn clauses

Tags: first-order-logic

I have a set of closed formulas and i put them into clauses. I noticed that some of them are not horn clauses. For example i have:

```
not(S(x)) or L(x) or B(x)
```

Is it possible to apply the resolution principle using this clauses ?

ps: why in resolution principle we have to use the most general unifier ? Isn't a particular unifier sufficient ?

Comment: You can see the post [SLD Resolution and Logic Consequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2659933/sld-resolution-and-logic-consequence).

Comment: See also the post [Syntax (Prolog Style)- resolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668692/syntax-prolog-style-resolution).